How to configure dense layers dimension for a classification model of 2130 classes?
I'm doing a classification task for chinese character with 2130. What is the best practice for setting up dense layer?
number_of_classes = 2130
SResnetModel = Sequential(
    [
        Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(224, 224, 3)),
        tflow.keras.applications.ResNet50(
            include_top=False,
            pooling='avg',
        ),
        Flatten(),
        Dense(2048,activation = 'relu'),
        Dense(number_of_classes,activation = 'softmax')
    ]
)
SResnetModel.summary()

Here is the summary.

I have done a little bit of searching and found that it's optimal to have the second last dense layer to have bigger dimension than the number of classes but how i can configure this.
